# Auto populate Account name on child object while click on "Save & New" standard button

Tags: custom-object, master-detail, button-overrides, save-and-new

I have created a custom object and created a Master-details lookup field to Account.

While creating new records, there is an issue.  When I click on New button, fill in all the fields and click on "Save & New" then It's working.  If I open an existing record, click edit and then click on "Save & New button". its not working(not auto-populating account name).

Please help!

Thanks in Advance